# check a radio button using name and value properties in core javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to select a radio button based on it's name and value properties.

```
<div id="p1sync" class="form-group">
     <label>P1 Sync :</label>
     <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="0" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Not Used</h5>
     <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;1 Person Price</h5>
     <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Person Price</h5>
     <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="3"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Room Price</h5>
</div>
```

i tried this but it didn't work,

```
document.getElementsByName('p1sync').value = 2;
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns `collection`

Comment: @Rayon is there is a way to select a radio button, using its name?

Comment: There are many elements having same name..Use `checked` property and select element using `value`

Comment: @Rayon thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns collection which does not have `value` property.

Use `value` attribute to select the element as there are many elements having same `name`

> Use [**`querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the element using `value` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="p1sync"][value="2"]').checked = true;
```

```html
<div id="p1sync" class="form-group">
  <label>P1 Sync :</label>
  <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="0" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Not Used</h5>
  <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;1 Person Price</h5>
  <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Person Price</h5>
  <h5><input type="radio" name="p1sync" value="3"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Room Price</h5>
</div>
```